# Can I use AWS Sagemaker like Google Colab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, amazon-sagemaker

I don't want to make use of any advanced features or automation. I just want a Python Notebook that can access cloud GPUs, and is persistent, so that I can close my laptop, and it will keep running in the cloud.
I understand Sagemaker is a paid service, but Colab just doesn't cut it for me sometimes: I need to keep my laptop running, there is only a limited quota and a chance that the session will timeout.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's sort of hard to compare them feature by feature but the closest experience you can have to Colab is using [SageMaker Studio](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/studio/).

Just keep in mind that the main value of SageMaker is that it decouples different steps of ML workflow. Therefore you can have a small instance running to build and develop your models in the Studio, then train that model on your data (has to be stored in S3) on a powerful instance(s) (with or without GPUs) as a "Training job" and then use that trained model for inference either at realtime (SageMaker Endpoints) or in batch (SageMaker Batch Transform).